# How can I Remove elements from a list

Tags: r, subset

How would I remove the elements that are zero form this list:

```
d <- list(c(1, 2, 0, 6, 0, 7, 7, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0))
d[1]
```

so the result would be `d[1] = 1, 2, 6, 7, 7, 9, 7`

Comment: Do you really want a list with a vector in it, or do you want just the vector?

Comment: I want the same list back just with the the zeros removed

Answer (score 4):

If it's a list with a single element containing a vector (as in your example), you can do:

```
d[[1]] <- d[[1]][d[[1]] != 0]
```

If the list has multiple elements, and you want to remove zeroes from each:

```
d <- lapply(d, function(x) x[x != 0])
```

(The latter expression would also work for a list with just one element.)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a list with a vector in it:

```
#    list(  vector                  )
d <- list(c(1,2,0,6,0,7,7,9,0,7,0,0))
```

None of your "list elements" are 0, because your list has a single element that is a long vector, not 0.

```
length(d)
# [1] 1
```

My guess is what you want is just the vector:

```
vec <- c(1,2,0,6,0,7,7,9,0,7,0,0)
```

In which case you can do

```
vec <- vec[vec != 0]
vec
# [1] 1 2 6 7 7 9 7
```

If you really do want the list, you'll need double brackets to select a single element for editing or use `lapply` and a function, as in @jbaums answer.